# Selenium Python - Clicking an image link got error: Message: element not visible

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to stimulate the onclick event for login and below is the html sample

```
<div id="divAccInfoDefaultLoginButton" style="display:inline">
    <a href="#" onclick="OnClickLogin();return false;" 
        onmouseout="if ( !isInSSOChecking() &amp;&amp; !isInEKBA() &amp;&amp; EnableAccInfo() ) { loadMouseEventImage('pic_login', 'pic_login'); }" 
        onmouseover="if ( !isInSSOChecking() &amp;&amp; !isInEKBA() &amp;&amp; EnableAccInfo() ) { loadMouseEventImage('pic_login', 'pic_login_on'); }">
        <img id="pic_login" border="0" src="./images/btn_login_ch.gif?cv=L3.01R2" title="登入">
    </a>
</div>
```

I try to click both href or the image but both failed as **selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible**

```
href = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='divAccInfoDefaultLoginButton']//a")
href.click()

img= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='divAccInfoDefaultLoginButton']//a//img")
img.click()
```

What is the correct way to stimulate the click action to trigger the onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

add `WebDriverWait()` also you need to switch to `iframe`

```
loginFrame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "betSlipFrame")))
driver.switch_to.frame(loginFrame)

# Login box visible click it
href = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='divAccInfoDefaultLoginButton']//a")
href.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with title as **登入** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#divAccInfoDefaultLoginButton>a[onclick*='OnClickLogin']>img#pic_login"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divAccInfoDefaultLoginButton']/a[contains(@onclick,'OnClickLogin')]/img[@id='pic_login']"))).click()
  ```
- Note : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```